# Android, Butterknife, BindView, Final

Tags: java, android, butterknife

There's probably a simple answer to this, but trying to use Butterknife to the fullest, converting some findViewById's into @BindViews, and noticed that I can't use BindView on views that I need to declare as final because Java raises an error that 'Variable 'x' might not have been initialized'.

Obviously, I don't need to use BindView, but just curious about this one to learn more about java. I read a bit about what the final declaration means, but couldn't tie it back to Butterknife. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not related to butterknife. If you want to initialize a   `member` declared as final, you can either do it at the moment of the declaration or in the constructor. In the case of `findViewById` and, hence, `Butterknife` , those two options are off the table. In both cases you use `findViewById` which needs a valid `context` object and can be successfully used after `setContentView`, and those two conditions are never met, when it comes to initialize `final` members. Please, be aware that `ButterKnife` uses code generation and behind the scene it still uses `findViewById` as you would normally do

Comment: this appears to work in the code:
final EditText randomvar = (EditText) activityReference.findViewById(R.id.randomID);

Comment: Inside a method and after setContetView, of course it works

Comment: Ok, that's where the confusion comes from, because that line of code is called inside of a class external to the activity, yet the activity being referred to has had setContentView called.